# Confusion regarding independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two unbiased dice are rolled. Let A be the event that sum is $6$ and $B$ be the event that sum is $9$.

> Are these events independent?

Intuitively it seems that these events are independent. But, $P(A)=5/36$ and $P(B) =4/36$ and $A \cap B = \phi$ so $P(A \cap B) =P(A) P(B) $ is not satisfied. What am i missing here?

Comment: Before reading the answers below, take your time to try articulating (to yourself or, even better, editing the question) what independence of events means; then, comparing your intuition against the 'correct' answers will be meaningful and instructive; I suggest this because this concept may be less straightforward than it cursorily seems. $\quad$ Also, take a look at points 1 & 3 of my explanation here: [Common mistakes in probability](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/26107/372).

Comment: Intuitively *to me* it seems that these events are *not* independent.  And then you give an excellent reason for why they are not independent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I intuitively see independent events?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948568/how-can-i-intuitively-see-independent-events)

Answer (score 3):

The events $\{Sum=6\}$ and $\{Sum=9\}$ are disjoint (can't happen both in the same experiment), and information that one event occurred in the experiment, gives information that the other did not occur, so intuitively, the events are dependent.

I guess you confuse *disjoint* and *independent*.

Comment: +1 See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/380791/2958 for an illustration of the distinction

Answer (score 2):

Why does your intuition suggest that they're independent?

To put it more simply, if the sum of two dice is $6$, then can it ever be $9$?. So do you see the dependence now?  If $A$ and $B$ were independent then $A$ and $B^{c}$ would also be independent. But here $A\subset B^{c}$ .

Answer (score 2):

A and B are dependent, because (as the question should be read) they are about the same dice roll. In fact they are exclusive events (the sum can't be both 6 and 9), which if the events can occur at all implies dependent (for the reason stated in the question).

What's independent is the outcome of *distinct* dice rolls. Like: the event that in a first throw of two dices they sum to 6 is independent of the event than in *another* throw they sum to 9.

Comment: "*A and B are dependent, because they are about the same dice roll.*" Events associated with the same dice roll need **not** be singular: for example, [in a single roll of a fair dice, the event of obtaining 3 or 6, and the event of obtaining 2 or 4 or 6, are independent of each other](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/26107/372).

Comment: @ryang: yes. My "if" was a shortcut for "if we read the question as about the same dice roll". I didn't mean that events about the same dice roll are necessarily dependent, which would have been wrong (example: dice roll is even, dice roll is less than 3).

Comment: I'm not understanding; the OP's two events are indeed regarding rolling one pair of dice.